# IdentityServer4 Issues

Tags: identityserver4

I am creating a web API security using IdentityServer4. I installed the identityserver4 package by typing the following syntax in the console manager: Install-Package IdentityServer4 -Pre. It gets installed successfully. Now i cannot reference it in my project. 
Here is my project.json code after installation:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",

    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
        "IdentityServer4": "1.0.0-rc1-update2"
    },

    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini"
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { },
        "dnxcore50": { }
    },

    "publishExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.xproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ]
}
```

So now i have created a client class with the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LearningIdentityServer4.OAuth
{
    public class Clients
    {
        public static IEnumerable<Client> Get()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new Client
                {
                    ClientId = "myApi",
                    ClientSecrets = new List<Secret>
                    {
                        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
                    },
                    ClientName = "My lovely Api",
                    Flow = Flows.ResourceOwner,
                    AllowedScope =
                    {
                        Constants.StandardScope.OpenId,
                        "read"
                    },
                    Enabled = true
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

So I get many errors. When I hover my mouse over let's say the first client, the only options i am getting is Add Package IdentityServer3 2.1.1

So how do i reference the IdentityServer4 instead of IdentityServer3 2.1.1

I would looking forward to hearing from you.

Thanks, Somad

Comment: You can also check a sample on how to set this up here: https://github.com/georgekosmidis/IdentityServer4.SetupSample

Answer (score 5):

Those frameworks are totally outdated.

To use identityserver4 you need to (at minimum) depend on `netcoreapp 1.0` framework with some added dependancies. replace your frameworks in your project.json to the following:

```
"frameworks": {
"netcoreapp1.0": {
  "imports": [
    "dotnet5.6",
    "portable-net45+win8"
  ]
}
},
```

Also see the [samples](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples). I assume either your tooling is outdated, or you are opening up an old project again. Lots of stuff has changed with ASP.NET Core.